# Is there a DOM function which deletes all elements between two elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have twenty three web components within the body element, twenty one of them are between the navigation menu (header) and the footer. Is there a function which could delete all elements between the navigation menu and the footer?

Comment: Use one more container element to wrap them all in and empty that container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Loop over the elements there and delete them one by one.

```js
const start = document.querySelector("nav");
const end = document.querySelector("footer");
while (start.nextElementSibling && start.nextElementSibling !== end) {
  start.nextElementSibling.remove();
}
```

```html
<nav>Navigation</nav>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quentin gave a great answer, and a useful demo that I can steal. ;)

Here's a similar approach using the "general siblings" combinator `~` and the `:not()` pseudo class. Because we get a collection, we can iterate over it, performing a `.remove()` on each element.

If there are text nodes to remove, this will not handle those.

Note that this will go beyond the `footer` if there are any other elements there, which may not be what you want.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("nav ~ :not(footer)")
  .forEach(el => el.remove());
```

```html
<nav>Navigation</nav>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```